# CSS Animation on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

I am using a CSS flip animation to show content on one side and text on the other. The animation works using a hover selector on desktop browsers. On mobile devices it should use a touch event to carry out the flip.

It works on edge, chrome and firefox and I have added additional CSS to handle older versions of IE.

However when I run it up on my iPhone I cannot get the the flip animation to work as expected.

I have attached a fiddle to show the issue I am having.

https://jsfiddle.net/rsmith93/oehqd5j6/

```js
$(".flip-container").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 360px;
  height: 270px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 1);
  color: white;
}

.name1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <!-- front content -->
          <span class="name1">panel 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <!-- back content -->
          back panel
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="flip-container" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <!-- front content -->
          <span class="name1">panel 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <!-- back content -->
          back 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="flip-container">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
          <!-- front content -->
          <span class="name1">panel 3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <!-- back content -->
          back 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Where's the fiddle? Also what version of iOS/safari ware you using?

Comment: @Poootaatoooo Apologies, i forgot to add it, updated my question. Running iOS 10.3.3

Comment: I believe the newest versions of iOS Safari don't need any prefixing so I won't make this an answer yet, but have you tried with the `-webkit-` prefix? (ie. copy and paste each transform line, but make it `-webkit-transform`)

Comment: @Poootaatoooo Ah thanks, that's improved the behavior of the touch events